# Google Calendar

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm developing one web application project using java for education industry.In this Admin have all rights to access the google services of other users like A,B,C..... for this is use OAuth.Then i tried Admin want to share user A's calendar to user B using OAuth.But i got stuck in this step. Is it possible Plz Help me

Thanks
Regards
Sharun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use Access Control Lists (ACLs), see [the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#SharingACalendar).  The Java example code at this URL for the task you mention is pretty simple:

```
AclEntry entry = new AclEntry();
entry.setScope(new AclScope(AclScope.Type.USER, "jdoe@gmail.com"));
entry.setRole(CalendarAclRole.READ);

URL aclUrl =
  new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/jo@gmail.com/acl/full");

AclEntry insertedEntry = service.insert(aclUrl, entry);
```

and what it does is, and I quote:

> This code allows jdoe@gmail.com to
>   have read-only access to
>   jo@gmail.com's calendar.

There's more where this came from (e.g., upgrading a user's role in an ACL above the read-only access granted in this example), and I think it's a good idea to read the whole page.